# I want to show nearby restaurant's in google map inside my React Native App. When i call Google API nearbysearch it throws status: 'ZERO_RESULTS'

Tags: javascript, android, reactjs, google-maps, react-native

Here is my code,

```
const url = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?' + 'location=' + latitude + ',' + longitude + '&radius=100&type=restaurant&key=<My API Key>';
        fetch(url)
            .then((response) => response.json())
            .then((JsonResponse) => {
                // console.error(JsonResponse)
                console.log(JsonResponse)
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                alert('error')
            });
```

Can someone guide me to how to do it, I am new to React Native.
Thank You

Comment: Perhaps there aren't any results within 100m of that location.

Comment: What're the values for latitude and longitude?

Comment: Maybe, I too guess that  @geocode

Comment: That's my current location Lat lang values @evan

Comment: Okay and do you get the same zero_results status code when using other lat/lng coordinates? What if you increase the radius to e.g. 10000? Or use a different type or none at all? If you get results in such situations then it's likely that there are simply no restaurants found within 100 meters from your current location.

Comment: I tried multiple lat/lang with 100 radius, getting zero results. When I change the radius to 1000 or above with same lat/lang got result.

Comment: Please check out my answer @Sriramkathirvel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google's documentation on [Status Codes](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/search#PlaceSearchStatusCodes) says the following:

> `ZERO_RESULTS` indicates that the search was successful but returned
>   no results. This may occur if the search was passed a `latlng` in a
>   remote location.

This looks like it's just a matter of the API being unable to find results, because you're looking for restaurants within 100 meters of a given (and possibly remote) location.

Note that the API does return results for your query when the `location` is set to `-33.8670522, 151.195736` (a point in Sydney, Australia) instead:

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=-33.8670522,151.1957362&radius=100&type=restaurant&key=KEY
```

In your case, since the latitude and longitude correspond to your current location, what you can do is increase the `radius` within which to search.

Hope this helps you!